# How to handling more than 1000 api request using NSUrlsession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsessionconfiguration

```
-(instancetype)initWithDataTaskWithUrlRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request WithIdentifierIndex:(NSString*)identifier
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self uuid]]];
        configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
        operationSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
        _sessionDataTask = [operationSession dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    }

return self;
}
```

I have a operation queue. And In each `NSOperation` i have used session to downloading the content. I have `ephemeralSessionConfiguration` and `DefaultSessionConfiguration`. It is working fine for 200 0r 300 operations. But when the operation increase to 1000 to 1000+ it will give me **time out,  handshaking error**. Please help me for best solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the same `NSURLSessionConfiguration` you can add/Increase timeout as :

```
 configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest  = KTimeOutValue; //Your timeout value
```